# Qt kits in the Qt Creator greyed out

Tags: qt, pyqt, qt-creator

Qt Creator 13.0

[image]

and because of it, I get an error:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
**Edit -> Preferences -> Kits**
Choose the desired Qt kit, scroll down, under **Python** dropdown it said '*None*' so I had to choose my installed version. Now it works=)